# problem with importing SGDOneClassSVM from sklearn.linear_model

Tags: python

I'm trying "from sklearn.linear_model import SGDOneClassSVM"
but it doesn't work and raises an import error "ImportError: cannot import name 'SGDOneClassSVM' from 'sklearn.linear_model"

Comment: What's your sklearn version?

Comment: i'm using the old version, 0. 23. 2

Answer (score 0):

Upgrade sklearn package using the command:

pip install --upgrade scikit-learn